# How to deal with database initialization?

Tags: installation, jpa-2.0, netbeans-platform

As also described [here](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html), I'm trying to determine the best way to initialize and update my application's database. I use EclipseLink-JPA2. I distribute a NetBeans platform application.

Considered options:

- use create-tables ddl-generation:
  The problem with this is that everytime the application runs it will throw exceptions, failing to create the tables. It will be useful only at setup time. This would be similar to placing checking code in the module restored() method.
- include the database with the application distribution: the ddl-generation strategy becomes do nothing. I could still use the JPA (at development time) to generate the database files (embedded Java DB).

The best solution would be for the installer/setup (first-time) to call initializing code that creates the database. This precisely what I do with JWS in [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/memorizeasy/files/MemorizEasy.jnlp/download). But I don't know how to do that without JWS. A script/jar executed by the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribute your NetBeans Platform application via JWS.

It seems like you already have this problem sorted out with JWS, so just use that solution to deploy your NetBeans platform app.

**EDIT**

An alternative approach would be to use a [Module Installer](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqAppLifecycleHooks) that checks for the existence of a config file. If the file exists then the application has been run before and the setup is not required. If the file doesn't exist then run your setup steps.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-login.html#installer), they're using a module installer to create a login dialog.

Comment: the only issue is that JWS runs the setup code at every update too, and thus I need to implement logic that distinguishes first-time installs from updates.

Comment: @simpatico I've added an edit about the Module installer functionality that I think you where also talking about. I Reckon that its most probably your best bet as you've got the most control.